# Antlr4 grammar actions run on discarded parses

Tags: parsing, antlr

I'm building my own AST data structure by adding actions to a grammar (just like I did with yacc, long ago---but this time, using Antlr4).  While the generated parser builds correct ASTs, it's a terrible memory hog.  A little instrumentation shows that up to 95% of the objects constructed by my actions and returned by grammar rules are discarded and don't end up in the final tree.  I suspect this is due to the generated parser using a backtracking strategy instead of relying solely on lookahead.  Is there a way to disable backtracking so I can test this hypothesis?  I'm using the antlr-csharp-4.0.1 system under Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR 4 does not use backtracking or speculative execution of actions in any scenario. Actions are only ever executed on paths that are actually parsed. Note that if you have semantic predicates, those may be executed during prediction, and may be executed multiple times.

Your version of ANTLR 4 is significantly out of date. The latest version of the C# target can be found on this page:

https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/releases/latest